# Laravel Third Party API User Verification

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use a API which has a postable address where you can verify if a customer's username/password is correct, if so it returns a user ID.

What would be the best way of handling this, I need to query that postable API from the login form on my Laravel website to see whether or not a username / password is validated.

How can I use Laravel's Middleware to store a USER ID and session securely?
How can I create a Laravel session to allow someone to login to my Laravel site using their WHMCS client login?

The API I am using is https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/validatelogin/

Comment: So what's a problem? There is a code how to send something on API via cURL by link above... Or you can use Guzzle HTTP client.

Comment: I understand how the cURL request works, however I don't understand how to correctly create a user authentication on the Laravel side of the project.

Comment: Manually you can do: Auth::login($user_id)

Comment: So, send that form data, validate the user, and pass the returned user ID from the API into Auth:login($userID) ? That would be secure and fine?

Comment: So, you don't have users in your Laravel site, right? Do you want a WHMCS user to login to your app with WHMCS credentials?

Comment: Yea, exactly. My Laravel site is completely database-less, I wish to authenticate user's via that API, and store their USERID into a session.

Comment: Well, it is not that simple. You should use oAuth authentication provided by WHMCS and in addition use Laravel Socialite.
Try to figure it out: https://developers.whmcs.com/oauth/auth-workflow/
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite

Comment: This solution wouldn't work as WHMCS oAuth only works for linking user-accounts, not verifying them. I.e, they would have to have a account on the Laravel side, plus, my WHMCS installation doesn't have a login/register functionality, that is performed through the Laravel site.

Comment: Have you already implemented this API call to create users inside your WHMCS database?
https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/adduser/

Comment: Yes, I am currently using that to allow users to create accounts. However, I still haven't figured out how to let them login yet.

Comment: Ok, try to read this: https://docs.whmcs.com/OpenID_Connect
and this: https://socialiteproviders.com/Whmcs/#installation-basic-usage
I think these links explain better than me how to achieve what you need.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however using this method would mean, on the login screen, there would be a button ' Login with WHMCS ' for example, then that button would redirect to my WHMCS installation. The problem with this is, there is nothing to redirect to. No WHMCS login page, nothing to forward to at all.

Comment: Do you find the result? As I am also looking for the response you have mentioned above?